# How to create pagination that based on two sql queries? (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I have page that display information from two different tables , and for that I have two queries.
There is no related info between these two tables.
Since both queries may contain a lot of information, I need create pagination.
BUT I don't want two separate paginations, I want only one that will contain results from query 1 and query 2 together.

How can I do that?

The only idea I have is to fetch all info of both queries into arrays, then combine the arrays into one, then create pagination that based on that array.
That of course would not help save resources.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a union - the columns you're displaying must line up, so something like this should work:

```
select
  col1 col1_alias,
  col2 col2_alias,
  ...
from 
  table1
where
  ...

union

select
  col1,
  col2,
  ...
from
  table2
where
  ...
order by col1_alias, col2_alias
limit 10
```

Basically the union will pull all the data together, and the `order by` and `limit` will apply to the whole result set.

The names of the columns don't need to match in the second select, but use column names from the first select for your `order by` (or create aliases, which is probably more readable depending on your dataset).